# Making a custom Pagination for multi page blog post

Tags: posts, customization, css, pagination

I am building a multi page guide in wordpress and would like to set it up so readers can click on a chapter and be taking that page. I know about the   code but i would like my Pagination to appear at the top and bottom and be the titles of my sections not numbers.

Can this be done? here is an idea of what I want. [image]

I have tried plugins but most don't work with the page builder i am using. I am hoping I can use css and html.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Early modern", "Religion" and "Parks and gardens" are true WP pages, then [wp_page_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/) is your friend.

Your `page.php` template would look something like the following:

```
// code to output page header, etc, would be above this

$args = array (
    'show_home' => false,
    // see below for info on the 'walker' arg
    'walker' => new My_Walker_Page_With_Featured_Image (),
    // any other wp_page_menu() args you want
    ) ;

// output the "top" page menu
wp_page_menu ($args) ;

// code to output page content goes here

// output the "top" page menu
wp_page_menu ($args) ;

// code to output page footer, etc, would be below this
```

`wp_page_menu()` outputs an HTML unordered list, the list items of which are links to the page in question.  You can style this list any way you'd like.

The main complication, looking at your desired page design, would be getting the image to appear in the menu items.  If it were me, I would probably do the following:

1. set that image as the page's featured image
2. subclass [Walker_Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_page/) and pass an instance of that subclass as the value of the `walker` arg to `wp_page_menu()`

   1. in that subclass's [end_el()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_page/) method, add the page's featured image to the list item

The following probably doesn't do *everything* you'd need to do, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
class My_Walker_Page_With_Featured_Image
    extends Walker_Page
{
    /**
     * append the page's featured image to the list item
     */ 
    function
    end_el (&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail ($page->ID) ;
        parent::end_el ($output, $page, $depth, $args) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. thats a lot more than i had to work with before. i will give it  try.